# MySQL multiple WHERE AND/OR condition logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have an SQL WHERE statement which is
(this or this or this) AND (this or this or this)

So any of the first parentheses AND any of the second parentheses.

```
AND ((li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 5) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 6))
AND ((li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 223) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 229) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 247))
```

Why won't this return any results?

Doing just the first part, works fine:

```
AND ((li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 5) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 6))
```

and so does if I just do the second part:

```
 AND ((li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 223) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 229) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 247))
```

But not both combined. Which should return results if the way I'm thinking is right!

Comment: It should be an OR at the start of the second line of code.

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618053/the-correct-way-to-store-items-with-a-filterable-attributes?noredirect=1#comment112497023_63618053

Comment: That is an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `OR` instead of `AND` in the second condition

```
AND ((li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 5) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 6))
OR ((li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 223) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 229) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 247))
```

`AND` makes both the conditions valid and returns no results

Below is the right way of providing the condition,

```
 AND ((li.MSAttributeID in (82, 85) AND li.MSAttributeValID in (5, 6, 223, 229, 247 )) OR (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 6))
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just ignore anything in the first parentheses though?

Comment: Yes it will ignore. Or you can use a different approach as well

Comment: Provided the right way of defining the logic, please use it

Comment: Thanks Jim, please can you explain it? It looks to me it is searching for any of those ValIDs (5,6,223,29,247) in either AttributeID 82 or 85, but I might not want to find ValID 223 in Attribute 82, this would return incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions simplified for readability can be written like this:

```
AND ((x = 82 AND y = 5) OR (x = 82 AND y = 6))
AND ((x = 85 AND y = 223) OR (x = 85 AND y = 229) OR (x = 85 AND y = 247))
```

or even simpler:

```
AND (x = 82 AND y IN (5, 6))
AND (x = 85 AND y IN (223, 229, 247))
```

Now since there are only `AND`s the parentheses can be removed and the condition is:

```
AND x = 82 AND y IN (5, 6) AND x = 85 AND y IN (223, 229, 247)
```

As you can see you have:

```
x = 82 AND x = 85
```

which is always `false`
and also:

```
y IN (5, 6) AND y IN (223, 229, 247)
```

which is always `false`.

So the result of the Boolean expression is `false` and you get no results.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
AND (
  (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID IN (5, 6))
  OR 
  (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID IN (223, 229, 247))
)
```

Comment: Hi forpas, that's a fantastic reply, thank-you. This doesn't solve an issue though with the results I get. For example, it should only show results where the AttributeID = 82 and ValID = 5, and those same results has AttributeID 85 and ValID 223. If I use OR, then it will just get all results of on of these 2 statements, where I would of thought an AND statement would solve this, as I want both statements to be true, not either or.

Comment: `AttributeID = 82 and ValID = 5` and `AttributeID = 85 and ValID = 223` can't be true for the same row, so what you say: *I want both statements to be true* is not possible. I think it is better to post sample data and expected results and explain what you want.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, you're right. I have 3 tables, a product table and a properties table and a property values table. A product can have multiple properties and multiple values, so I am trying to select products where it has EVERY property but ANY value for that property. At the moment, it's ANY property and ANY value. This might not be achievable in SQL, perhaps creating an array then filtering them out with PHP instead? Thanks.

Comment: I can't say if it is achievable or not without actual sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you have 2 combinations of MSAttributeId and MSAttributeValID. Then in your second line you have another 3 combinations. I think what you want is to return results that match any of those 5 combinations. So what you really want is:

```
AND 
(
   (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 5) 
OR (li.MSAttributeID = 82 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 6)
OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 223) 
OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 229) 
OR (li.MSAttributeID = 85 AND li.MSAttributeValID = 247)
)
```

I will add that the reason your two lines joined with the AND returned no results is because by doing so you were saying that MSAttribteID had to equal both 82 and 85 at the same time - which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn't return the correct results as I need in my example the first statement to return true AND the second statement, if it's OR, then it can just ignore the first statement.