# The correct way to store items with a filterable attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently had an issue with some SQL logic over here: [MySQL multiple WHERE AND/OR condition logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600558/mysql-multiple-where-and-or-condition-logic/63601065) and realised that its most likely the way I structure my data. I'm dribbling at the screen a bit on what the best way to do this is.

There is a list of **products**, which are cars.

These cars have **attributes**, they aren't compulsory, some might have more than others: Color, Size, Wheels

These attributes then have **values**, Color: Red, Green, Yellow, Blue. Size: Small, Medium, Large. Wheels: 2, 4, 6.

I want to find results of cars that match ALL the attributes that are selected ANY of the values, some examples:

1. All cars that are (red OR blue) AND small AND 2 wheels
2. All cars that are (red OR blue OR yellow) AND (small OR MEDIUM)
3. All cars that are small AND (2 wheels OR 4 wheels OR 6 wheels)

Before, I stored these results in a table where there was a product ID and a attribute ID and a value ID, a row for each variation. The problem was as the other thread I mentioned earlier, I can't query this with AND as it returns false. e.g. I can't search a table for a row that is color red AND color blue. It must be one or the other. That works fine but then it will show every other result regardless of what I am trying to select since it bounces off the OR statement.

I thought about storing this data in an array/delimiter-separated value instead? I just want it to be easy to query.

Comment: There's a difference between queries "easy to write" and "performant queries". Which one do you want to prioritize?

Comment: post your sql here ! the conditional brackets should be properly closed - if not, it would result like this.

Comment: Just use Elasticsearch, it's going to be far much superior than querying a sql database using gazillion of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using aggregation for this with conditional aggregation.  For instance, for your first bullet:

```
select a.carid
from attributes a
group by a.carid
having sum( (attribute, value) in ( ('color', 'red'), ('color', 'blue') ) ) > 0 and 
       sum( (attribute, value) in ( ('wheels', '2') ) > 0;
```

The `> 0` means that the attribute/value combination exists.  Use `= 0` to specify that it does not work.

Comment: do you mean "Use `= 0` to specify that it does not exist does not work."?

Comment: This works great using > 0, thank-you so much. So happy to of solved this. Not heard of "having" before.